accessing return value from a task inside taskgroup in airflow dag
I have a dag where I am using task decorators to pass the xcom's and task group to loop over a task.
At the moment, to be able to run the loop inside taskgroup, I have to pass the a hardcoded list. The list is returned by the task but I cannot access it inside the taskgroup. Is there any way I can achieve this to get away from hardcoding?
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'start_date': days_ago(1)
}

with DAG('taskgroup', schedule_interval='@daily', default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:

    @task
    def extracting():
        return ['A','B','C']

    with TaskGroup('processing_task_group') as processing_group:
        **for l in ['A', 'B', 'C']:**
            BashOperator(task_id=f'processing_{l}', bash_command='ls')

    loading = DummyOperator(task_id='loading')

    extracting() >> processing_group >> loading`

I tried using the XComArg and get_current_context but the taskgroup doesn't understand any of those.
What could be the best way to remove the hardcoding.
